# jekyll component with content defined in the front matter

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am new to jekyll and liquid, so Im not sure if this is easy or not. I have banged my head against this for hours. I have a component which is located in my includes, I pull it into a page. Here is the include

```
<div class="point-list">
<p>{{ page.point-list }}</p>
</div>
```

It is usually pulled multiple times on a single page, which are written in mardkdown.

```
{% include Components/point-list.html %}
```

I want each of those instances to have different content, but I can only define "point-list" once in the front matter. I can create front matter called point-list-1, point-list-2 etc but Im not sure if theres a way for the include to read the order. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Use parameters for includes. See http://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/

Answer (score 0):

As David Jacquel already said: Use parameters for includes.

You can call them like this:

```
---
point-lists:
  - html: '<p>content number one</p>'
  - html: '<p>content number two</p>'
---

{% include Components/point-list.html number=1 %}
{% include Components/point-list.html number=2 %}
```

The 'point-list.html' should look like this:

```
<div class="point-list">
{{ page.point-lists[include.number].html }}
</div>
```

I have not tested this. Please let me know if you find any errors.